# Am I able to change my GPA once I submit a graduate school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gpa

I am wondering if I apply to graduate school in US in fall and lets say the due date to submit the application is December 1 and fall quarter grades are posted two weeks after that. Now I am wondering am I be able to update my GPA after positing the fall quarter grades,which is after submitting the application?

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on the school you are applying to:

You can call their administration that you would like to hand in recent new transcript, or just send it to them and hope they accept (it should certainly not be a bad thing to do it).

Comment: Thanks. I know after I get accepted I should send my final transcript to them but what I meant is that do they send us as email that please update your application?

Comment: @user59419: They probably won't send you an e-mail requesting further information (once you have completed your application), but you can send them an e-mail offering it.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that create somehow unequal situation.You look at grades and see if it is good you will email them and if it is bad you will ignore it. The same for all applicants.

Comment: @user59419 Yes, but you have absolutely no cost of trying it out. Conversely, if you are better than previously submitted, you should fairly be granted to show it.